# How to make automatic formatting of a java file seperate methods with 2 lines on VSC

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, formatting, customization

I want to make VSC add 2 lines automatically between methods as part of the 'Format Document' keyboard shortcut (`Shift` + `alt` + `f`).

I shifted from Eclipse to VSC a couple of weeks ago and in Eclipse I had the option to freely customize pretty much any part of the document's auto-formatting. I've been searching for a way to do this on VSC but I couldn't find what I'm looking for. Not sure if it matters but I'm writing my code in java.

Basically what I want to happen is:

```
public class Testing {

   public void func1() {
      //Some code
   }

   public void func2(){
      //Some code
   }

   public void func3(){
      //Some code
   }
```

`Shift` + `alt` + `f` ==>

```
public class Testing {

   public void func1() {
      //Some code
   }


   public void func2(){
      //Some code
   }


   public void func3(){
      //Some code
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **Command Palette** and choose **Java: Open Java Formatter Settings with Preview**, then there'll be an notification popping up, click `Generate a default profile`, then `java-formatter.xml` will be displayed in the folder `.vscode`.

Open `java-formatter.xml` and set :

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_method" value="2"/>
```

[image]